# Python: Using del in for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, del

I was iterating through a list with a for loop, when I realized del seemed to not work. I assume this is because i is representing an object of the for loop and the del is simply deleting that object and not the reference.

And yet, I was sure I had done something like this before and it worked.

```
alist = [6,8,3,4,5]  

for i in alist:  
    if i == 8:  
        del i
```

In my code its actually a list of strings, but the result is the same: even though the if conditional is satisfied, deleting i has no effect.

Is there a way I can delete a number or string in this way? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea as to why you are seeing that behavior is correct.  Hence, I won't go over that.

To do what you want, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (it is available in the old [python2](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as well) to filter the list:

```
>>> alist = [6,8,3,4,5]
>>> [x for x in alist if x != 8]
[6, 3, 4, 5]
>>> alist = [6,8,8,3,4,5]
>>> [x for x in alist if x != 8]
[6, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

This approach is also a lot more efficient than a for-loop.

Comment: Hmmm. And what happens if you do `alist = [6, 8, 8, 3, 4, 5]`?

Comment: @NickSimas - Actually, my old post was wrong.  I didn't think right. :*)  My new one is what you _should_ be using.

Comment: Why did you not like your first answer? It was the exact answer I was looking for.

Comment: Try running it with the sample list @glglgl gave.  It won't get rid of all the 8's.  The current one will.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Oh well, Ill just add counter = alist.count(8) and then put for i in range(counter) in front.

Answer (score 2):

`del` does not delete an object. It simply decrements the reference count of the object referenced by its argument. In your code

```
alist = [6,8,3,4,5]  

for i in alist:  
    if i == 8:  
        del i
```

you have 6 objects: 5 separate integers, and a list of 5 references (one per integer). The `for` loop works by executing its body once per element in `alist`, with `i` holding a reference to a different element in `alist` in each iteration. Whichever object is referenced by `i` has a reference count of at least 2: the reference held by `alist` and `i` itself. When you call `del i`, you are simply decrementing its reference count by making `i` point to nothing.

While the following *techinically* works, by deleting all (known) references to the object, it has its own problems (involving modifying a list you are currently iterating over) and should not be used.

```
>>> alist=[6,8,3,4,5]
>>> for i, a in enumerate(alist):
...   if a == 8:
...     del a        # delete the loop index reference
...     del alist[i] # delete the reference held by the list
>>> alist
[6,3,4,5]
```

Instead, simply use a list comprehension to build a new list to replace the old one

```
alist = [ x for x in alist if x != 8 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop assigns a new value to `i` at each run.

So, essentially, your `for` loop above does

```
i = 6
i = 8
del i
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
```

which has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to use del you need to use it on the list:

```
del alist[i]
```

(note that in this case `i` is an index, not the value you want to remove)

But really here you should probably just create another list using list comprehension:

```
[x for x in alist if x != 8]
```

Comment: `del alist[i]` would raise IndexError if i == 8. You should be clear that `i` is an INDEX, as opposed to the `i` in the question - which is the VALUE.